# Linking  c++ dll with Haskell-Platform on Windows,  outputs 'undefined reference'

Tags: gcc, haskell, mingw, iconv

I am a Haskell enthusiast and have got stuck upon compiling my little Haskell program on Windows. My program uses the [iconv](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/iconv) package, which in turn uses the foreign library written in c/c++. To  make things work I have :

- Run [GNU-Iconv](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm) setup and added its 'bin' folder, where
  'libiconv-2.dll' and 'libiconv2.dll' are located,  to  the `PATH`
  variable.
- Extracted and copied 'LibIconv developer files' to the 'mingw' folder of
  Haskell Platform location.
- Then 'cabal install iconv' compiles and I have the cabal package
  installed.

Now, when I try to build my module in Leksah, I get the following message from 'GHC':

```
Building norms-parser-0.0.1...
Linking dist\build\norms-parser\norms-parser.exe ...
C:\Documents and Settings\kdv\Application Data\cabal\iconv-0.4.1.0\ghc-7.0.4/libHSiconv-0.4.1.0.a(hsiconv.o):hsiconv.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `_imp__libiconv_open'
C:\Documents and Settings\kdv\Application Data\cabal\iconv-0.4.1.0\ghc-7.0.4/libHSiconv-0.4.1.0.a(hsiconv.o):hsiconv.c:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `_imp__libiconv'
C:\Documents and Settings\kdv\Application Data\cabal\iconv-0.4.1.0\ghc-7.0.4/libHSiconv-0.4.1.0.a(hsiconv.o):hsiconv.c:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `_imp__libiconv_close'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

With 'GHCi',I face an issue too:

```
ghc.exe: unable to load package `iconv-0.4.1.0'
ghc.exe: C:\Documents and Settings\kdv\Application Data\cabal\iconv-0.4.1.0\ghc-    7.0.4\HSiconv-0.4.1.0.o: unknown symbol `__imp__libiconv_open'
```

I think the probable  solution  is in having the right setup of c/c++ header files to 'mingw' folder and setting PATH variables to 'lib' files, but I have little knowledge about it, so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This is an old problem with libiconv. Maybe this thread would be of help: http://www.mail-archive.com/gnuwin32-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00858.html

Comment: UPDATE. Thanks for your reply. Diving in deeper and find answers:

http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2011-February/089234.html and here 
http://www.progtown.com/topic190618-haskell-iconv-on-win32-iconvopen.html

Comment: @Ivory -- if you've found the answer, you should post it and accept it.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I'm facing a similar problem with GHC 7.6.3 but I assume it's an incompatibility issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing libiconv is a little tricky on Windows.

1. Download libiconv **binary** and **developer files** from [it site here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm)
2. Unzip both packages over mingw folder, which is inside your Haskell Platform folder.
3. Download cabal package for Iconv [latest version for the moment](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/iconv-0.4.1.2)
4. Edit iconv.cabal file, so lines with `include-dirs` and `extra-lib-dirs` will looks like

   ```
   include-dirs:    cbits, "C:\\HaskellPlatform\\2013.2.0.0\\mingw\\include"
   extra-lib-dirs:  "C:\\HaskellPlatform\\2013.2.0.0\\mingw\\lib"
   ```

notice the double dashes in windows path, and edit it to your path of Haskell Platform.

1. Edit iconv.cabal file, there is a line with `if os(darwin) || os(freebsd)`, change it to `if os(darwin) || os(freebsd) || os(windows)`
2. Thats it, now you can run `cabal install` command from iconv pachage dir