# How to make libiconv work for hsexif on windows

Tags: haskell, sublimetext, cabal

So I've spen about a day now tryin everything and to no avail. I have at least successfully installed (I'm not 100% it's successful but it didn't complain) the iconv-0.4.1 lib which I need for hsexif lib I'm desperately trying to use.

After all the trouble I'm left with an error

```
photo_test.hs: C:\Users\Dito\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\iconv-0.4.1.2\HSiconv-0.4.1.2.o: unknown symbol `__imp_libiconv_open'
photo_test.hs: photo_test.hs: unable to load package `iconv-0.4.1.2'
```

Now the package is installed and I have pasted the lib files from gnu website all over my pc. My only guess is that I need to add a path to some linker somewhere in the sublime files.

What should I do?

Comment: I am the author of `hsexif`. I am aware that `iconv` is a pain to install on windows. `hsexif` uses `iconv` only for minor side tasks (like decoding EXIF comments). You could download the `hsexif` source code and strip the `iconv` dependency and fix the code to make it passthrough the encoding conversions, assuming you use only ASCII letters. I could also migrate hsexif to `text-icu` but it also depends on a C library, might not help. Otherwise maybe look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972662/linking-c-dll-with-haskell-platform-on-windows-outputs-undefined-reference

Comment: I wish you came sooner ;(

Comment: too bad you didn't open a bug against `hsexif` on github :-) Maybe I'll make encoding conversion optional one way or the other. Because `text-icu` doesn't seem much better than `iconv`: http://w3facility.org/question/what-is-the-proper-way-to-handle-string-encoding-in-haskell/ (22Mb of dependencies! and still DLLs to work with)

Comment: https://github.com/emmanueltouzery/hsexif/issues/7

Comment: Yeah I was really stupid for not adding hsexif tag :/ How did you find this question?

Comment: well the hsexif tag doesn't exist I believe and I'm not registered to it :-) I just googled `hsexif` randomly :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the proper answer would be something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972662/linking-c-dll-with-haskell-platform-on-windows-outputs-undefined-reference). I know it can be made to work, as I did it once. Still, the second time I actually gave up as it was just too messy and very annoying to make it work. As I wrote in a comment to your question, the good news is that `hsexif` needs the `iconv` dependency only to be able to nicely format the EXIF `User Comment` field, which is rarely used.

Therefore you would be probably happy enough with an `hsexif` built without that feature. So I've just uploaded a new `hsexif` version on hackage, 0.6.0.4, which has a build flag to request to build without the `iconv` dependency:

```
cabal install hsexif -f-iconv
```

Be sure to update your cabal package DB first though: `cabal update`.